# CSS property dependent of element position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My **goal** is to show a styled tooltip in an HTML document.

Therefore I created this code:

```css
.word-with-tooltip{
  position:relative;
 }
  
.tooltip{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:1.5em;
  right:0;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  display:none;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:gray;
  background-color:#dddddd;
  text-align:left;
 }

.word-with-tooltip:hover .tooltip{
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<div style="height:200px"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="word-with-tooltip">
      Left Car
      <div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="word-with-tooltip">
    Centered Car
    <div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
    </span>
  </div>
<div style="text-align:right;">
  <span class="word-with-tooltip">
    Right Car
    <div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
  </span>
</div>
<div style="height:200px"></div>
```

Rudimentary this does what it should do: when hovering a word with the mouse, the browser shows a formatted tooltip:
[image: HTML word with styled tooltip]

Unfortunately the tooltip is cut off when it is too far at the left:

[image: Tooltip cut off]

A solution would be to set the CSS property `left` instead of `right` in dependence of where the word with the tooltip is positioned. The position can vary because it can be anywhere in a large text.

**Question**: Is it possible (and how) to ...

1. set CSS property `left:0` if the word is positioned at the left half of the screen?
2. set CSS property `right:0` if the word is positioned at the right half of the screen?
3. set CSS property `top:1em` if the word is positioned at the upper half of the screen?
4. set CSS property `bottom:1em` if the word is positioned at the lower half of the screen?

Comment: If there's a way to do this without JavaScript, I sure don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".word-with-tooltip").forEach(word => {
  word.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    const tooltip = e.target.children[0]
    if (!tooltip) return;
    tooltip.style.cssText = `
      ${( e.clientX * 100 ) / window.innerWidth < 50 ? 'left' : 'right' }: 0;
      ${( e.clientY * 100 ) / window.innerHeight < 50 ? 'top' : 'bottom' }: 1em;
    `
  })
})
```

```css
.word-with-tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: gray;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
}

.word-with-tooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:200px"></div>
<div>
  <span class="word-with-tooltip">
      Left Car
      <div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
    </span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <span class="word-with-tooltip">
    Centered Car
    <div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
    </span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:right;">
  <span class="word-with-tooltip">
    Right Car
    <div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
  </span>
</div>
<div style="height:200px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one approach:
I added these styles:

```
.word-with-tooltip.left .tooltip{left:0;}
.word-with-tooltip.right .tooltip{right:0;}
```

... and assigned them dynamically within a onmouseover event.
That code looks like this (where I split up the content of the `onmouseover` attribute for the sake of readability):

```
<div>
<span class="word-with-tooltip"
onmouseover="
this.classList.remove('left');
this.classList.remove('right');
if(event.clientX<window.innerWidth/2){
    this.classList.add('left');
} else {
   this.classList.add('right');
}">
Left Car
<div class="tooltip">A vehicle with four wheels</div>
</span>
</div>
```